# Is there a way to show a twitch channel being hosted on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to showcase streamers on my website through twitch and hosting, however the current method i am using only shows the main channel to be offline. This is the current method i am using.

```html
<div class="live"><iframe
            src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=BlueBirdRP"
            height="600"
            width="80%"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            allowfullscreen="true">
        </iframe></div>
```

Comment: Maybe that's because the channel's offline...

Comment: You're doing it right according to their documentation: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/